# How can I catch UTM Cookies values?

Tags: c#, cookies, google-analytics, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm trying to Log into a website using `WebRequests` in `C#`  But the website is using **Google-Analytics** libraries which is making some `UTM-Cookies`
The question is how can I catch those cookies values and pass them to the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class has a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) collection property that you can add instances of the [`Cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.aspx) class.

The [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) class has a [`Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx) collection property that contains instances of the [`Cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.aspx) class.

Make your request, read the cookies from the response, and add them to any subsequent requests as needed.

Comment: Its not working for GoogleAnalytics coz thats called from a JS

Comment: Do you mean that the call to Google-Analytics is done with AJAX?

Comment: AJAX calls only send cookies that match the domain of the request address.  You would have to set the domain in your request cookies.

Comment: Follow the JS link, you will get the cookie!